# How to sort the array list maximum value on first position

Tags: android

I want to sort the array list with having maximum value in first position. Currently I am doing as shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str_position.size(); i++) { 

                            int position_id = str_position_id_one_time;
                            position_id--;
                            Log.e("position_id---=------>",""+position_id);
                            str_position_id_one_time = position_id; 
                            array_bitmap_grid_adpater.remove(Integer.parseInt(str_position.get(i)));
                            adapter_GridView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Sort the array list maximum value on first position ex : [0, 1, 5, 3] i need [5, 3, 1, 0]

Comment: apply bubble sort algorithm and print in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way for your `list`:

```
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

OR 
this one line

```
Collections.sort(unsortedArrayList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

First sort it then reverse it ;)

Comment: its not sorting if the array count more that 10         ex :  [4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 8, 5, 2, 1]
this is sorted array [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 11, 10, 1]

Comment: @user3790247 this happens when you use string array, please confirm

Comment: yes im sorting the string array , if i changed to integer means works perfect thanks all

Comment: Yes it works great if you're using int array :) Please up-vote and mark as correct so we can help others to find correct solution :)

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion :

```
your_array.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others :)